# Seeking User Testing Tool for Small 1 Person Company

Tags: software-testing

My question is regarding testing software for a small UX business owner. My company is currently 1 person... me.

I use [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com) at work, but we pay a hefty price for it. I wanted to find out if anyone can recommend a tool that is comparable to Optimizely or at least a simple A/B testing platform for a small business owner? I was hoping for something that can allow me to grow my business, without breaking the bank.

Appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Hotjar might be an option, for Heatmap and Drop-off comparison at least. They have free plans.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=alternative+to+Optimizely+

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=Optimizely+

Answer (score 0):

If your site has Google Analytics, [Google Optimize](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize/) is included. It will let you set up basic A/B tests through your Google Analytics tag.